# Proving slope inequality when function is concave up

Tags: calculus, derivatives, slope

I'm trying to prove the following question:

> Suppose that $f$ is concave up on an interval $I$ and $x_1, x_2, x_3$
> and $x_4$ are numbers in $I$ with $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < x_4$. Show that
> the slope of the  secant line through the points at $x=x_1$ and
> $x=x_3$ is less than the slope of the  secant line through the points
> at $x=x_2$ and $x=x_4$.

Now using concavity [theorem](http://psibi.in/velleman-calculus/chapter4/section4.html#sec-1-2), I have been able to derive the following equations:

$\dfrac{f(x_3) - f(x_1)}{x_3 - x_1} < \dfrac{f(x_4) - f(x_3)}{x_4 - x_3}$

$\dfrac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} < \dfrac{f(x_4) - f(x_2)}{x_4 - x_2}$

Rewriting the above equations as:

$m_1 < \dfrac{f(x_4) - f(x_3)}{x_4 - x_3}$

$\dfrac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} < m_2$

My objective is to prove that $m_1 < m_2$

I also know that:

$\dfrac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} < \dfrac{f(x_3) - f(x_4)}{x_3 - x_4}$

Now i'm stuck at this point. I'm not exactly sure how to proceed so as
to prove $m_1 < m_2$.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question 'slope of line btw $x=x_2,x=x_2$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Yes. Fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove:

$$m_1 < m < m_2$$
where $m = \dfrac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3-x_2}.$ The most elementary way to proceed would be to make use of the following simple fact: if $c,d > 0$ and $\dfrac ac < \dfrac bd,$ then

$$\dfrac{a}{c} < \dfrac{a+b}{c+d} < \dfrac{b}{d}.$$

You can prove the above easily by expanding and then use this for appropriately chosen $a,b,c,d$ to obtain both sides of the equality you want to prove.

Comment: While I'm able to prove $m_1 < m$, I'm not sure how to prove $m < m_2$ part using the technique you have mentioned.

Comment: @Sibi see the edit - I forgot to include the other side of the inequality.